# Wrong line break in description environment after a long label

Tags: line-breaking, description

I encountered an issue with my description environments: If I use a label that almost is as long as the text width, the explanatory text afterwards is not wrapped correctly.

I am using the `mdwlist` package with the `description*` environment, but the problem is reproducible also with the normal `description` environment (see example below).

Searching for similar problems did not help me so far, because most topics deal with labels that are longer than the text width, which can be treated with the `\desclabelwidth` command of `mdwlist`.

What I found so far is that there is the command `\desclabelwidth` to control the width of the label, and `\labelsep` to control the width of the separator after the label. Now I think my problem is that the text in the first line after the label is longer than `\textwidth` - `\desclabelwith` - `\labelsep`. Is there any way to control this width, or do you know any other way to circumvent the problem?

EDIT: I found my problem has to do with my BCOR settings - I set the value to 15mm, then the problem occurs also with short words.

Many thanks!

Here my minimal working example - the word "text" does not fit into the line and in my opinion could as well go into the next one. Instead, I get this warning:

> Overfull \hbox (12.03125pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--10

```
\documentclass[BCOR=15mm]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{Issues with descriptions}

  \begin{description}
    \item[A normal label.] A text with short words, nicely wrapped. One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
    \item[A very long label that is almost as long as the text width, but not quiet.] A text with short words, not so nicely wrapped. One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
  \end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the code shown below]

Comment: Thank you for posting this question. It is particularly problematic in twocolumn documents, when the label of a description is more likely to use up most of the column width.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You've found a very unfortunate combination: there's no possibility to hyphenate "text" and breaking the line after "A" would make the line underfull.

A reason for this is that the text in the description label is typeset in a box, so it doesn't participate in the possible stretching of spaces to justify the line.

With the `enumitem` package we can change this behavior, by "unboxing" the label. Such an adjustment is not necessary (neither desirable) if the label is short; when it's very long it may be.

If you say

```
\documentclass[BCOR=15mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Issues with descriptions}

\begin{description}[style=unboxed]
\item[A normal label.] A text with short words, nicely wrapped. One two
three four five six seven eight nine ten.
\item[A very long label that is almost as long as the text width, but not quite.] A text
with short words, not so nicely wrapped. One two three four five six
seven eight nine ten.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

then the label text will participate in the distribution of spaces in the line and the overfull problem will disappear.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I tried to use `enumitem` instead of `mdwlist`, but this does not work because I am working with `paralist`, which to my best knowledge cannot be used together with `enumitem`. 
In particular, I am getting the error 
> Undefined control sequence \end{enumerate}
whenever I am using an enumerate environment if both `enumitem` and `paralist` are loaded. This is why I was using `mdwlist` in the first place...

Comment: Anyhow, reading the documentation of `enumitem` makes me believe that maybe exchanging both `mdwlist` and `paralist` for `enumitem` will be worth the effort... I will give it a try.

Comment: @Jenny It's definitely better to switch: `mdwlist` is not maintained (last version in 1996); `enumitem` is more powerful than `paralist` and is actively maintained and developed.

Comment: You're definitely right - only 15 minutes of work, and I have replaced all uses of both `mdwlist` and `paralist` with the appropriate options in `enumitem`. It works and looks exactly as I wanted it to (inline lists and less spacing), only without the erroneous wrapping. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned, this is reproducible for the standard `description` environment, and happens even outside that as well. Your *warning* is

```
Overfull \hbox (9.53209pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--10
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 An ex-plana-
```

showing that TeX is struggling to properly break the word "explanatory" at the text block boundary. It can either hyphenate it as "ex-planatory" or as "explana-tory", both of which yield inappropriate spacing for that line (measured in "badness").

A solution would be to reword that particular phrase to avoid the problematic hyphenation. It's a simple fix for a common problem.

Comment: you can add a hyphenation exception: `\hyphenation{ex-plan-a-tory}` ... but it may not be enough.  (if this word isn't in the exceptions list that i maintain, it'll be added for the next iteration.)  rephrasing is almost certainly a better idea here.

Comment: If you (i) add the hyphenation exception instruction `\hyphenation{ex-plan-a-tory}` as per Barbara Beeton's suggestion above (TeX's hyphenation algorithm doesn't find the hyphenation point after the letter "n") *and* (ii) load the `microtype` package, you'll succeed in getting a line that's only 1.25pt too wide (rather than being nearly 10pt too wide). This situation, hopefully, will be barely noticeable to your readers.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I noticed it's true that in my example, the problem is the word "explanatory", which is not occurring in my real work. So I tried to reproduce the example with shorter words and found it has to do with my BCOR settings. I will edit my question and the example.