# Line break in description environment

Tags: line-breaking, description

My eldest son has made an important report for school based on a six month research (not full time).
I could convince him to use LaTeX as it is the best tool available to write it.
The final doc has 42 beautiful pages.
However, we have found a small issue on a line break.

Inside a description environment the first line extends too much to the right.
The same is described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55412/wrong-line-break-in-description-environment-after-a-long-label), but there the word could not be partitioned.
In this case it can be done and LaTeX already knows: `Overfull \hbox (7.30554pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--30[]\T1/cmr/m/n/12 l'all ac-tua`.
When the word is separated by hand it becomes still worse unless a line break is forced.
If the line break is forced no warning of `Underfull \hbox` is issued, so should it not be the preferred solution?

The solution, like in the other post, is to use package `enumitem`.
But why does this happen?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}

%\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}%[style=unboxed]
  %%% "actua" extends too much to the right
  \item[Efecte antiagregant plaquetari i activador de la fibrinòlisi:] l’all 
  actua com un anticoagulant, manté la fluïdesa de la sang. A més, degrada la 
  fibrina, una de les proteïnes que s’encarrega de la formació de coàguls 
  sanguinis.
  %%% suggesting hyphenation does not help
  \item[Efecte antiagregant plaquetari i activador de la fibrinòlisi:] l’all 
  ac\-tua com un anticoagulant, manté la fluïdesa de la sang. A més, degrada 
  la fibrina, una de les proteïnes que s’encarrega de la formació de coàguls 
  sanguinis.
  %%% hard coding the hyphenation does not give a good results either
  \item[Efecte antiagregant plaquetari i activador de la fibrinòlisi:] l’all 
  ac- tua com un anticoagulant, manté la fluïdesa de la sang. A més, degrada 
  la fibrina, una de les proteïnes que s’encarrega de la formació de coàguls 
  sanguinis.
  %%% hard coding the hyphenation and forcing a line break is still not optimal
  \item[Efecte antiagregant plaquetari i activador de la fibrinòlisi:] l’all
  ac-\\ tua com un anticoagulant, manté la fluïdesa de la sang. A més, degrada 
  la fibrina, una de les proteïnes que s’encarrega de la formació de coàguls 
  sanguinis.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With `style=unboxed` the problem disappears, because the interword spaces in the description participate to the stretching for the line.

Other strategies could be

1. Use `sloppypar`
2. Use `\linebreak` to emulate the hyphenation

Examples.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  %%% "actua" extends too much to the right
  \item[Efecte antiagregant plaquetari i activador de la fibrinòlisi:] l’all 
  actua com un anticoagulant, manté la fluïdesa de la sang. A més, degrada la 
  fibrina, una de les proteïnes que s’encarrega de la formació de coàguls 
  sanguinis.
  \begin{sloppypar}
  %%% works
  \item[Efecte antiagregant plaquetari i activador de la fibrinòlisi:] l’all 
  actua com un anticoagulant, manté la fluïdesa de la sang. A més, degrada la 
  fibrina, una de les proteïnes que s’encarrega de la formació de coàguls 
  sanguinis.
  \end{sloppypar}
  %%% use \linebreak rather than \\
  \item[Efecte antiagregant plaquetari i activador de la fibrinòlisi:] l’all 
  ac-\linebreak tua com un anticoagulant, manté la fluïdesa de la sang. A més, degrada 
  la fibrina, una de les proteïnes que s’encarrega de la formació de coàguls 
  sanguinis.
\end{description}

\begin{description}[style=unboxed]
  %%% works
  \item[Efecte antiagregant plaquetari i activador de la fibrinòlisi:] l’all 
  actua com un anticoagulant, manté la fluïdesa de la sang. A més, degrada la 
  fibrina, una de les proteïnes que s’encarrega de la formació de coàguls 
  sanguinis.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But why, when using "ac- tua" it is placed on the same line creating an Overfull hbox warning, instead of sending the last part to the next line which seems to not give an Uderfull hbox warning.