# No URL line break in description

Tags: line-breaking, urls, description

there are several ways to make a line break in URLs. But does somebody know how to break the URL in this example? Thanks, Harald

```
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    twoside,
    toc=listofnumbered,
    listof=flat,
    headinclude,
    footinclude,
    index=numbered
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % HJELE: für Silbentrennung von Wörtern mit Umlauten via \hyphenation
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=black,linkcolor=black,filecolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\begin{sloppypar}
\item[\normalfont{Thaney, Kaitlin (2009):}] Laying out the Principles of Open Science. Vortrag am {\glqq}Open Science workshop :: PSB 2009{\grqq}, 5.1.2009, Big Island of Hawaii.\\
Online unter:\\
\url{https://de.slideshare.net/kaythaney/laying-out-the-principles-of-open-science-presentation}
\item[\url{https://www.springer.com/de/autoren-herausgeber/deutsche-publikationen/buchautoren/buchautoren-manuskript-richtlinien}:] Richtlinien zum Publizieren für Autoren und Herausgeber des Springer Verlags.
\end{sloppypar}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: Line break in URLs]

Comment: With standard list environments you would never have line breaks in the label of an item. [You need at least package `enumitem` to unbox the label.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55415/277964) As an alternative, you could use a `\parbox` inside the optional argument of `\item`. However, it seems you are printing something like references. So you also could use [`biblatex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Comment: BTW: Using `sloppypar` for more than one paragraph, inside a whole `description` is not recommended. If you really need it for a whole environment, you could just use `\sloppy` inside the environment. But I would always recommend to use only for those paragraphs it is really needed. Maybe using `\raggedright` or `\RaggedRight` (see [`ragged2e`](https://ctan.prg/pkg/ragged2e)) would be better in your case (with all those `\\ `).

Comment: @cabohah what would be the syntax of an parbox within the argument of an item. ``` \item[\parbox{\normalfont{\url{https://www.springer.com/de/autoren-herausgeber/deutsche-publikationen/buchautoren/buchautoren-manuskript-richtlinien}}:}{11.7cm}] Richtlinien zum Publizieren für Autoren und Herausgeber des Springer Verlags.
 ``` wont work. Thx. Harald

Comment: The same as for a `\parbox` outside. You syntax is completely wrong, e.g., the text argument has to be the last one. So I would recommend to learn the correct syntax from a LaTeX introduction.

Comment: @cabohah Thx, this helps. Sorry, the \parbox was just in the wrong order. Not much to learn ;-) BibLaTeX is in this case not a real help. Harald

Answer (score 3):

Don't load the `breakurl` package, replace `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` with `\usepackage{xurl}`, and don't include URL strings in the arguments of items of a `description` list.

You might as well also replace `urlcolor=black, linkcolor=black, filecolor=black, citecolor=black` with `allcolors=black`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    twoside,
    toc=listofnumbered,
    listof=flat,
    headinclude,
    footinclude,
    index=numbered
]{scrbook}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl}
%%\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
%%\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=black]{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}

\item[]Thaney, Kaitlin (2009): Laying out the Principles of Open Science. 
   Vortrag am {\glqq}Open Science workshop :: PSB 2009{\grqq}, 5.1.2009, 
   Big Island of Hawaii.

Online unter:
\url{https://de.slideshare.net/kaythaney/laying-out-the-principles-of-open-science-presentation}

\item[]\url{https://www.springer.com/de/autoren-herausgeber/deutsche-publikationen/buchautoren/buchautoren-manuskript-richtlinien}: Richtlinien zum Publizieren für Autoren und Herausgeber des Springer Verlags.

\end{description}
\end{document}
```